# Browsers, other windows crashing 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: chromium

I use a Dell Precision M4800 with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

And I am having an issue where any browser I use (Chromium, Firefox) constantly crashes. Typically it just goes to the screen on Chromium,

> Aw Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

and similar messages. Occasionally I'll have all of my windows crash (close completely). I have ran a memory test and it appeared to be fine (not an expert).

Comment: Has this happened since you installed it? Was there something you did update etc. just before this started to happen?

Comment: It has been happening since before I installed the newest version. It has been an issue ever since installing Ubuntu on this system.

Comment: And yes it has happened since I upgraded.